# Cтатистический метод проверки разницы между квартилями

Tags: r, статистика

Учитывая имеющиеся данные, я разделил их на квартили на основе разницы между двумя временными точками (T_diff). Я хочу сравнить, если каждая мера (Measure) в квартиле 1 статистически отличается от квартилей 2, 3 и 4.

Пример:

```
T_diff (days)   Measure 1       Measure 2        Quartile
1                  0.01             0.9              1
2                  0.02             1.1              1
3                  0.02             1.2              1
10                 0.1              1.3              2
11                 0.2              1.1              2
12                 0.2              2.0              2
12                 0.3              2.1              2
38                 0.124            3.9              3
39                 0.5              0.1              3
41                 0.2              0.8              3
385                0.1              0.4              4
390                0.4              1.5              4
390                0.8              1.7              4
```

В реальных измерениях распределение не являются нормальным.

Я нашел ks-test, который используется в таких случаях. Однако я сомневаюсь, могу ли я его применить здесь?

Comment: `glm()`? и попробовать различные `link functions` в зависимости от того, на что похоже распределение